# Simple multivariable limit problem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I evaluate the following limit?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} (x^2+y^2)}$$

It seems like this limit would be some finite nonzero number, but I don't have too much experience calculating limits with multiple variables. Any type of hint would be of great help.

Comment: When you have $x^2+y^2$ stuff, which is often, going to polar coordinates is often useful. In our case, after simplification, we get $\cos^3\theta$. As $r\to 0$, the behaviour of this is highly sensitive to the behaviour of $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Fantastic advice, André Nicolas. So after switching to polar coordinates, the above limit becomes $\lim_{r \cos(\theta)\to0} \cos^3(\theta)$, right? Or is it just $\lim_{r\to0} \cos^3(\theta)$?

Comment: It is $r\to 0$. The variable $\theta$ can wiggle all over the place. If we pick $\theta=\pi/2$ we get limit $0$. If we pick $\theta=0$ we get limit $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** The limit doesn't exist. For example, consider the paths $x = 0$ and $y = x$.

Comment: Also, using polar coordinates gives a different result.

Comment: Good answer, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\alpha x$ to get $\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} (x^2+y^2)} = { x^3\over \sqrt{1+ \alpha^2}(1+\alpha^2) |x|x^2} = { x\over \sqrt{1+ \alpha^2}(1+\alpha^2) |x|}$.

Now let $x \downarrow 0$ to get the limit 
$+{ 1\over \sqrt{1+ \alpha^2}(1+\alpha^2)}$
and $x \uparrow 0$ to get the limit 
$-{ 1\over \sqrt{1+ \alpha^2}(1+\alpha^2)}$.